# Wordpress - Show custom fields of children on parent page

Tags: wordpress

I'm using the [Advanced custom field](http://plugins.elliotcondon.com/advanced-custom-fields/) plugin and having trouble showing custom fields of children in a loop. I tried this:

```
<?php <br /> $pages = get_pages(array('child_of' => $post->ID));

foreach($pages as $page) 
{
setup_postdata($page);
$fields = get_fields(); print_r($fields);
}

wp_reset_query();
?>
```

When I put `print_r($page)` in it says 1111 so that bit is working (as there's 4 children items).

That code just prints the custom field names of the parent rather than the children, how can I show the children's custom fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should've been post instead of page, doh!

http://support.plugins.elliotcondon.com/discussion/43/show-page-children-or-subpages-with-custom-fields

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
get_pages(array('child_of' => $post->ID, 'parent' => $post->ID, 'hierarchical' => 0))
```

Comment: The problem is more with the custom fields and getting them to show. Not sure that would make a difference would it?

Comment: oh ok, we'll looks like you found the problem :)